# iOS is it possible to play local notification sound when device is on mute

Tags: ios, notifications, local, mute

I'm developing alarm clock which needs to wake up when receiving local notification. but when the device on mute I cannot hear anything, I'm asking because I saw 2 apps which implemented that i.e (radio alarm).
thanks, tomer.

Comment: well that's gonna annoy everyone in the theatre...

Answer (score 3):

Check out `AVAudioSession`'s `setCategory` function -- it should do the trick for you.

Here's a link for info on the categories: [developer.apple.com - Audio Session Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html)

Answer (score 0):

RadioAlarm, I'm almost certain, is able to play when muted because it keeps itself running in the background.  For a NORMAL local notification (i.e. one that fires even after the app finishes), I have not found a way to overcome the mute switch or the ringer volume.

Comment: Do you know of a way to play an audio alert on a local notification but playing a .wav file that is not in the bundle? For example, if I record my voice saying "Buy milk" and I set the notification for 2pm.. i get the notification but I want the sound to play without user intervention.. ?

Comment: Apple explicitly does not let you access .wav files that are not in the bundle. So since you are not allowed to trow files in the bundle without breaking the signing. Thus it is not possible to play sounds that are not included from the start in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)playSound:(NSString *)filePath
    {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:0];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        [self.audioPlayer play];
    }
```